# Is there a way to script password change for multiple Softlayer IDs?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a lot of SL ids and would like to change the passwords in a script. Is this possible using the API? Any samples are appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify more please? Do you want to change user's passwords?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. If I’m right, you want to change the user’s passwords of an Account. I’ll provide you some references that can help you:

First to change a user’s password, you can use:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_User_Customer/updatePassword

> Note:  The users can only update their own password. An account's
>   master user can update any of their account users' passwords. As I
>   don’t know what language you are using, below there is a REST example
>   using a Master User of my Account to update a child user: URL:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_User_Customer/[ User_Customer_ID]/updatePassword
```

Method: POST

Json payload

```
{
"parameters": [
"Yourpassword1#"
]
}
```

To get user’s information of you r account (i.e. User_Customer_ID), please see:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers

I hope this information help you

Comment: I would like to change passwords for multiple SoftLayer accounts via a script. The admins of the account provided default passwords and I don't want to use the Portal to login and change each account password 1 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a brand account and you have created several accounts, the way to change the password for all those accounts is login to the accounts using impersonation and call the method SoftLayer_User_Customer::updatePassword method. I have this example to login to your accounts in your brands (it is using the Softlayer ruby API client and SOAP request ), you need to change the SOAPs to call the updatePassword. I hope it helps

```
# Creates new account and create API key for that account
#
# The script creates a new account using the createCustomerAccount() method,
# then the script will create the API key for that account, in order to achieve
# that goal it is necessary to make soap request because in oder to create
# the API key we need to call the method addApiAuthenticationKey() using the
# the credentials of the new account as we do not have that information we are
# calling the method using impersonation.
# For perform the impersonation we need the userId and the token for the authentication.
# For more details please see below.
#
# Important manual pages
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/addApiAuthenticationKey
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getApiAuthenticationKeys
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getOwnedBrands
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Account/
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Brand/
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand/createCustomerAccount
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand/getUsers
# http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand/getToken
#
# License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
# Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc.<sldn@softlayer.com> require 'softlayer_api' require 'pp'

# Your SoftLayer API username and key. USERNAME = 'set me' API_KEY = 'set me' ENDPOINT = 'set me'

# Declaring the API client to use the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest API service client = SoftLayer::Client.new(   username: USERNAME,   api_key: API_KEY,   endpoint_url: ENDPOINT )

brand_service = client.service_named('SoftLayer_Brand') account_service = client.service_named('SoftLayer_Account')

begin   # Getting the brand for our account   # the account could belong to several brands   # you need to select one brand for the new account.   brands = account_service.getOwnedBrands

  # Creating an SoftLayer_Account object which contains the data   # of our new account.   account_template = {
    'address1' => '8200 Warden Ave',
    'city' => 'Markham',
    'companyName' => 'IBM Bluemix Dedicated',
    'email' => 'email@softlayer.com',
    'firstName' => 'FirstName',
    'lastName' => 'Surename',
    'officePhone' => 'number',
    'postalCode' => 'L6G 1C7',
    'state' => 'TX',
    'brandId' => brands[0]['id'],
    'country' => 'CA'   }

  # Creating the new account   new_account = brand_service.createCustomerAccount(account_template)

  # Looking for the master user for the new account   new_master_user
= nil   users = brand_service.object_with_id(brands[0]['id']).getUsers   users.each do |user|
    if user['accountId'] == new_account['id']
      new_master_user = user
      break
    end   end

  # Getting the token   token = brand_service.object_with_id(brands[0]['id']).getToken(new_master_user['id'])

  print token # This is the token you need to send to the SOAP request print '  '   print new_master_user['id'] # This is the userId you need to send to the SOAP request

rescue StandardError => exception   puts "Unable to create the new account : #{exception}" end

# Here call the soap methods

=begin This is a soap example to create the API key to the account. It will create the API key for the master account of the new account. In case the master account already has an API key the request will return an error. Please replace the values $TOKEN and $USERID

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:clientLegacySession>
      <userId>$USERID</userId>
      <authToken>$TOKEN</authToken>
    </ns1:clientLegacySession>
    <ns1:SoftLayer_User_CustomerInitParameters>
      <id>$USERID</id>
    </ns1:SoftLayer_User_CustomerInitParameters>   </SOAP-ENV:Header>   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:addApiAuthenticationKey/>   </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

You Also can execute this SOAP request to get the APIKey of the master account Note: The user should already has the APIKey created

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://api.service.softlayer.com/soap/v3/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:clientLegacySession>
      <userId>$USERID</userId>
      <authToken>$TOKEN</authToken>
    </ns1:clientLegacySession>
    <ns1:SoftLayer_User_CustomerInitParameters>
      <id>$USERID</id>
    </ns1:SoftLayer_User_CustomerInitParameters>   </SOAP-ENV:Header>   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getApiAuthenticationKeys/>   </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

=end
```